# Адаптивная верстка брейкпойнта <767px на Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

У меня возникла проблема с адаптивной версткой на экранах меньше 767px, вот пример разметки из 6 колонок:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при достижения брейкпоинта @<767px и меньше, две первые колонки были сверху одной строчкой и занимали по 50% каждый всей ширины, третья колонка была второй строчкой и занимала 100% всей ширины, четвертая и пятая колонка занимали третью строчку обе так же по 50%, ну и шестая колонка занимала бы последнюю строчку на 100% ширины?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
      6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно.